# Alarm manager setRepeating for only fixed number of days

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I need to set an alarm, which will go off, at a particular time for a fixed number of days. I am aware of setRepeating method, which will keep triggering an alarm, after the specified time interval. But I need it to trigger only for some specified time duration.

For eg: I have the `'start date', 'end date', 'interval' and 'time to trigger'` from the user. Now the alarm should trigger only from start date to end date. 
How should I implement this?

Comment: either dont use `setRepeating` (use just one shot) or stop it after `end time`

Answer (score 0):

Check Whenever alarm is schedule to check if end_date has reached , if it has then cancel the alarm , or use alarmManager set method to set alarm each time after checking the end date